# Creating charts based on user choice using user form and vba excel

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I manage to get my desired user form based on the selected data range with the following code below:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

Dim rng As Range
Dim ctl As Control
Set rng = Selection

For i = 1 To rng.Columns.Count - 1
    Set ctl = Me.Controls.Add("forms.label.1")
        With ctl
            .Name = "Series" & i + 1
            .Caption = rng.Cells(1, 1 + i)
            .Top = 15 + (i * 35)
            .Left = 24
            .TextAlign = 2
            .Width = 126
            .Height = 12
        End With
Next i

For i = 1 To rng.Columns.Count - 1
    Set ctl = Me.Controls.Add("forms.combobox.1")
         With ctl
            .Name = "ComboBox" & i + 1
            .Top = 15 + (i * 35)
            .Left = 216
            .TextAlign = 2
            .Width = 174
            .Height = 15
            .AddItem "Clustered Column"
            .AddItem "Stacked Column"
            .AddItem "Line"
            .AddItem "Stacked Line"
        End With
Next i
End Sub
```

But the issue is I can't seem to get my desired chart based on the choice made in the user form with this following codes:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Selection
Dim cht As Chart
Set cht = ActiveChart

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select

   With cht
        If cht.ComboBox2 = "Clustered Column" Then
            cht.FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        ElseIf ComboBox2 = "Stacked Column" Then
            cht.FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlColumnStacked
        ElseIf ComboBox2 = "Line" Then
            cht.FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlLine
        ElseIf ComboBox2 = "Stacked Line" Then
            cht.FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlLineStacked
        End If
    End With
    
    With cht
        If ComboBox3 = "Clustered Column" Then
            cht.FullSeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        ElseIf ComboBox3 = "Stacked Column" Then
            cht.FullSeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlColumnStacked
        ElseIf ComboBox3 = "Line" Then
            cht.FullSeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlLine
        ElseIf ComboBox3 = "Stacked Line" Then
            cht.FullSeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlLineStacked
        End If
    End With
    
    With cht
        If ComboBox4 = "Clustered Column" Then
            cht.FullSeriesCollection(3).ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        ElseIf ComboBox4 = "Stacked Column" Then
            cht.FullSeriesCollection(3).ChartType = xlColumnStacked
        ElseIf ComboBox4 = "Line" Then
            cht.FullSeriesCollection(3).ChartType = xlLine
        ElseIf ComboBox4 = "Stacked Line" Then
            cht.FullSeriesCollection(3).ChartType = xlLineStacked
        End If
    End With
            
Unload Me

End Sub
```

I've tried userform1.combobox2.value also can't seem to do the trick. I think it is probably because my combobox name is wrong? But I can't seem to find the name of my combobox since it is only available only if I run the 1st port of the code.

[image: Data Example]

Here is an example of the data I would like to chart it into stacked columns for police and doctor and line for total.

Comment: Please replace the image with the actual code.

Comment: You have done `Set cht = ActiveChart` *before* creating the new chart. when you `Set`, you're grabbing the current object at the time of executing that line. If you change which chart is active, `cht` doesn't re-target the new active chart, it remains targetting the one it has saved, even if that is `Nothing`.

Comment: Your first If Statement also says `cht.ComboBox2` which might be a mistake.

Comment: In the VB Window (Alt+F11), press Ctrl+R to bring up the project explorer. On the left side, you should now see a list of workbooks, and when expanded, a list of sheets and modules within each workbook. The first name, before the brackets, is the codename. If you write the codename in your code, you can reference that object. `Userform1` is the default codename for the first user form, but yours might not be `Userform1` especially if you imported it from somewhere.

Comment: I have removed the `Set cht = ActiveChart` and changed my first if statement to `Userform1.ComboBox2.value = "Clustered Column` when I run the code it shows **Compile Error: Method or Data member not found.** , I've also double checked that my codename is `UserForm1`. @Toddleson

Comment: Is it because my ComboBox is not created permanently? It is only being created if I run the code.

Comment: Use `Me` to reference the UserForm with the code, so `Me.ComboBox2.Value`.

Comment: You say `With cht` then `cht.FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlColumnClustered`. `With` means you should leave off `cht` before `.FullSeriesCollection`.

Comment: About chart types, note that you can't combine clustered and stacked columns in a chart, or line and stacked line. Also, a stacked line chart is dangerous, because it can easily be misread as a regular line.